# How to know event type in Jenkins Github Pull Request builded plugin?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, hook, github-api

I enabled the `Github Pull Request Builder` plugin from my jenkins, and there was jobs which trigger when new PR created. My current selection in GitHub enterprise are

[image: Current Selection]

I selected for `issue comments` and `pull requests`. I want to run some jobs when there are `pull request reviews`. How can we differentiate on jenkins side, like with events trigger this build ?